# Windows Authentication Does not Work for Some Users in AD

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

We have a website with Windows Authentication. We have the AD group defined in the web.config who can access the website. Some users in the AD group are able to login to the application. However, some other users are getting a prompt for credentials, but not able to login. What could be the reason for this behavior? How do we correct it?

Sample Structure of the config setting is:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Group1" value="XXX\AppleFruit.Red" />
</appSettings>
```

Note: The website is hosted in IIS7

Comment: I don't think there's enough info here to answer - the app setting is simply a key value/pair.  What does that have to do with integrated auth?  What type of files are getting denied?  What's ACLs on those?

Comment: Trying to access an aspx page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use built-in authentication/authorization?  In your web.config, you should use this:

```
<authorization>
  <allow roles="XXX\YourRoleToAllow"/>
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

This will allow access to your role, and deny to everybody else.

Comment: +1 - OK, this is auth specific (as opposed to generic key value)

Answer (score 0):

I do not actually know the reason behind your code's failure, but following code works for me fine:

```
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode=“Windows“/>
      <identity impersonate=“true“/>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles=“Domain\Group1“/>
        <deny users=“*“/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
```